# Print out Bytes received from Java to C

Tags: java, android, c, linux, sockets

I am trying to send bytes from Android phone to my Raspberry Pi. When i sent it over, I received some weird symbols in this form: 5000 + weird symbols. Bytes should only be in numeric form when received right?

This is my code on Android.

```
socket.getOutputStream().write(String.valueOf("5000").getBytes());
```

And this is my code for receiving on Raspberry Pi.

```
char Buffer[1024];
nread = recv(clientSocket,Buffer,1024,0);
printf("Data Received: %s",Buffer);
```

Clearly, I am very new to sockets. Also, the bytes I am currently sending in java should = the bytes I am receiving on RPI? Will be really grateful if someone can explain it to me !

Comment: Initialise with zeros: `char Buffer[1024] = {0};` will do too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code `socket.getOutputStream().write(String.valueOf("5000").getBytes());` sends 4 bytes, because Java use 16 bits chars ONLY for non ASCII character as specified in [Java Language Specification 3.10.5](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.5).

To be sure, you have to print the value of `nread` in C program.

The code `nread = recv(clientSocket,Buffer,1024,0);` receives 4 characters and DOESN'T put the zero to terminate the string, so printf display the contents of the (non initailized) buffer, I suggest `memset( Buffer, 0, sizeof( Buffer ))`

Code suggested:

```
if( nread < 0 ) {
   perror("Read error");
   return;
}
Buffer[nread] = '\0';
```

To encode and decode messages and streams I usually use [java.nio.ByteBuffer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html)

To encode and send **ASCII 7** java.lang.String:

```
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;

public final class SerializerHelper {

   public static void putString( String s, ByteBuffer target ) {
      final byte[] bytes = s.getBytes();
      target.putInt( bytes.length );
      target.put( bytes );
   }

   public static void putBoolean( boolean value, ByteBuffer target ) {
      target.put((byte)( value ? 1 : 0 ));
   }

   public static boolean getBoolean( ByteBuffer source ) {
      return source.get() != 0;
   }

   public static String getString( ByteBuffer source ) {
      final int len = source.getInt();
      final byte[] bytes = new byte[len];
      source.get( bytes );
      return new String( bytes );
   }
}
```

In C:

```
uint32_t len       = strlen( s );
uint32_t lenForNet = htonl( len );
char * p = buffer;
memmove( p, &lenForNet, sizeof( lenForNet ));
p += sizeof( lenForNet );
memmove( p, s, len );
send( sckt, buffer, len + sizeof( LenForNet ), 0 );
```

Comment: Worth mentioning that it's still a good idea to include the charset when getting the bytes to avoid surprises when a user *does* include non-ASCII characters in the input

Comment: Sorry I don't get it, so do i use memset or the code you suggested?

Comment: 'I suggest memset( Buffer, 0, sizeof( Buffer ))' - why would you suggest that waste of cycles when you already know where to put the NUL - [nread].

Comment: You have to initialize all the variables before use, in C language.
After a call, you have to check the return code because exceptions doesn't exists in C.
`nread` maybe negative or nul. recv may read less character than you expect. See man recv.

Comment: 'The code nread = recv(clientSocket,Buffer,1024,0); receives 4 characters' no, it does not have to.  It receives no more than 1024 bytes, but may receive less.  If 4 characters are sent, there is no guarantee that a call to recv() will load all the bytes representing the four chars into the buffer in one call.

Comment: 'You have to initialize all the variables before use,' no, not if you first use is to load them - that, in itself, is an initialization.  The memset/bzero/whatever of large comms buffers is just cargo-cult programming that wastes cycles for no gain.

Comment: With 'nread = recv(clientSocket,Buffer,1024,0);' and 'Buffer[nread] = '\0';', the receipt of all 1024 bytes would result in an out-of-bounds write of the NUL.   Either read [1024-1] or oversize the buffer to [1025].

Comment: @Aubin Hi Aubin, this time, I am trying to send string from C to Java. How should I convert it such that it receives properly in Java?

Comment: @Aubin Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Strings in Java are 16 bits.  If you want to send a string to C, convert to utf-8 first.  (Or use a 16 bit string library, but generally you'd convert to utf8).

Comment: oh i see! Okay I will try it after lunch. How do i know what buffer size i should set for the string?

Comment: No, consult : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.5

Comment: @Aubin just read it. It says nothing about character encoding in that section. I've never heard about java using 8 bit characters anywhere under any circumstances, and if it did whay you said I know quite a bit of code that works in the wild would be broken. I think you misread the past on it handling characters that take more than 1 16 bit characters to be more than 1 8 bit characters

Comment: I did a conversion by doing:  socket.getOutputStream().write(String.valueOf(progress).getBytes("UTF-8")); But it didn't work

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7921016/what-does-it-mean-to-say-java-modified-utf-8-encoding

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem. After searching and looking around stackoverflow, I followed the answer from this link. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/319576/problems-receiving-data-over-a-tcp-client-socket)

I did:

```
Buffer[nread] = '\0';
printf("%s",Buffer);
```

Answer (score 0):

Receiving from socket

```
char recv_data;
 while ((bytes_received = recv(connected,&recv_data,1,0)) > 0){
        printf("\nrecv= %c\n", recv_data);
        }
```

Sending from Java

```
 String datatosend = "5000";
   char[] strArray;
   strArray = datatosend.toCharArray();

   while (true) {
   for( int index = 0; index < strArray.length; index++){
       out.write(strArray[index]);
   }
out.flush();
```